# Javascript Object get object by property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have an object of 2 users that looks like the following. The Object will only ever contain 2 users.

```
{
   "71":{
      "avatarURL":"__vue_devtool_undefined__",
      "createdAt":"2018-10-13T16:05:19Z",
      "customData":"__vue_devtool_undefined__",
      "id":"71",
      "name":"Angeline Fadel",
      "updatedAt":"2018-10-13T16:05:19Z",
      "presenceStore":{
         "71":"online"
      }
   },
   "199":{
      "avatarURL":"__vue_devtool_undefined__",
      "createdAt":"2018-10-13T16:06:13Z",
      "customData":"__vue_devtool_undefined__",
      "id":"199",
      "name":"Rodrigo Schuster",
      "updatedAt":"2018-10-13T16:06:13Z",
      "presenceStore":{
         "71":"online"
      }
   }
}
```

Let's say my user ID is 199, how to I get the name of the other user without knowing it's ID?

Comment: Please do not post image.....instead post code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Object.keys`, you can get an array of keys:

```
const users = { 199: {...}, 71: {...} };
const ids = Object.keys(users); // -> ['199', '71']
```

Knowing that the array will only contain two items and the "other" key, you might use [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the other item:

```
const myId = '199';
const targetId = ids.find(id => id !== myId); // -> '71'
```

Remember that object keys are always strings, so you may want to tweak the filtering and operations on IDs in a way that they are treated as (or coerced into) numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the values using [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get ids. And then [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get other user

```js
let users = {
  '71':{name:"First User"},
  '199':{name:"Second User"}
}
let id = '199'
let otherId = Object.keys(users).filter(key => key !== id)[0]
console.log(users[otherId].name);
```

Comment: But what it the order of the users in the object change?

Comment: @itsliamoco sorry I think i misunderstood. I updated

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj={
  199: {
    name: "abc"
  },
  71: {
    name: "def"
  }
}

var knownKey = 199;
var otherKey = Object.keys(obj).filter(key => key != knownKey).pop();
console.log("name = " + obj[otherKey].name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by following code.  Suppose `obj` is the object and `id` variable stores the id. Now, use Object.keys to get the keys (which is array) and filter out the result based on `!== id`. Use `otherId` to get the relevant object and name.

```js
obj = {
   "71":{
      "avatarURL":"__vue_devtool_undefined__",
      "createdAt":"2018-10-13T16:05:19Z",
      "customData":"__vue_devtool_undefined__",
      "id":"71",
      "name":"Angeline Fadel",
      "updatedAt":"2018-10-13T16:05:19Z",
      "presenceStore":{
         "71":"online"
      }
   },
   "199":{
      "avatarURL":"__vue_devtool_undefined__",
      "createdAt":"2018-10-13T16:06:13Z",
      "customData":"__vue_devtool_undefined__",
      "id":"199",
      "name":"Rodrigo Schuster",
      "updatedAt":"2018-10-13T16:06:13Z",
      "presenceStore":{
         "71":"online"
      }
   }
}
id = "199"
otherId = Object.keys(obj).find(data => data !== id)
result = obj[otherId].name
alert(result)
```

Comment: Note that `otherId` is an array: `[ "71" ]` and not `71`.  It works probably because `[ "71" ].toString()` is `71`. You should use `find` instead

Answer (score 0):

You could get the ids using `Object.keys()` and filter them.

```js
const usrs = {
  '1': {
    name: 'a'
  },
  '2': {
    name: 'b'
  }
};

function other(usrs, id) {
  const allId = Object.keys(usrs);
  console.log('allId:', allId);
  const otherId = allId.filter(k => k !== id);
  console.log('otherId:', otherId);
  const otherUser = otherId.map(uid => usrs[uid]);
  console.log('otherUser:', otherUser);
  const otherNames = otherUser.map(u => u.name);
  return otherNames
}

console.log(other(usrs, '1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

```js
const users = {
   "71":{
      "avatarURL":"__vue_devtool_undefined__",
      "createdAt":"2018-10-13T16:05:19Z",
      "customData":"__vue_devtool_undefined__",
      "id":"71",
      "name":"Angeline Fadel",
      "updatedAt":"2018-10-13T16:05:19Z",
      "presenceStore":{
         "71":"online"
      }
   },
   "199":{
      "avatarURL":"__vue_devtool_undefined__",
      "createdAt":"2018-10-13T16:06:13Z",
      "customData":"__vue_devtool_undefined__",
      "id":"199",
      "name":"Rodrigo Schuster",
      "updatedAt":"2018-10-13T16:06:13Z",
      "presenceStore":{
         "71":"online"
      }
   }
};

const knowUserId = '199';
const knowUserIndex = Object.keys(users).indexOf(knowUserId);

if(knowUserIndex > -1){
 delete users[knowUserId]; 
}

console.log(users)
```